# Rackspace Server IP Points to Wrong Site

Tags: dns, rackspace

I have just taken over as a developer for a company. They host their development site on Rackspace. When I arrived, this server was spun down. Upon bringing it back up, I discovered that the IP address of that server points to the live website. There must be some kind of forwarding in place (I assume that it is through Rackspace) that does this. How can I fix this? I searched for settings on Rackspace to no avail. I would like to be able to access this dev site at least through the direct IP address until the network admin reappoints the develoment domain name to proper IP.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you mean the live website domain routes traffic through to this server?  Off the top of my head, you either have DNS load balancing in place - so an A record on your domain matching the IP address of the powered down machine  OR you have a load balancer within rackspace that is routing traffic to it.

Comment: No,I mean the opposite. Namely, when I spun up the server on Rackspace, it had an IP address. If that IP is input in the browser, it takes you to the live website (which is hosted entirely elsewhere).
No load balancers are set up on Rackspace.

Comment: Right. It's probably not the live website then - just a copy of it on the dev machine.

Comment: No, it is the live site to which it points. I am quite sure of that.

Comment: Interesting. Could be the web server on the dev box is reverse proxying requests to the backend proxies running your live site. Only way you can tell is to log in and follow the trail from the webserver downwards...

Comment: How would you do that? I am a relative newbie with this side of things. I tried to use the "dig" command in Linux to investigate, but it does not seem to give  much information.

Comment: First thing is work out the setup of the server. What web server is installed, what sites are installed, and how they are configured (locally configured you'd have a document root somewhere with a site), proxying somewhere else, you'd have a proxy declaration in the web server config.... so yeah - work out how the server is serving content (if at all) as your first step... And good luck :)

Comment: I answered it. It had only in part to do with the settings of the server. For some unknown reason, the Apache was pointing to a particular site/folder inside the www/directory. Then, a .php script would do a forward to that address. What is strange is that there were similar scripts for other sites in the same directory, but the program used that one.